# Different cache strategies in gradle profiler

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-profiler

I'm using a [gradle profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler) and I want to measure full clean build time. So, I think I should clean build caches before each execution.

Gradle profiler has multiple cache clearing strategies including:

- `clear-build-cache-before`: Deletes the contents of the build cache before the scenario is executed (`SCENARIO`), before cleanup (`CLEANUP`) or before the build is executed (`BUILD`).
- `clear-transform-cache-before`: Deletes the contents of the transform cache before the scenario is executed (`SCENARIO`), before cleanup (`CLEANUP`) or before the build is executed (`BUILD`).
- `clear-project-cache-before`: Deletes the contents of the .gradle and buildSrc/.gradle project cache directories before the scenario is executed (`SCENARIO`), before cleanup (`CLEANUP`) or before the build is executed (`BUILD`).

Questions

1) What is the difference between build, transform cache?

2) Should I also disable remote cache, or gradle profiler will disable remote cache automatically?